# SED Regex rewriting between two patterns using backreferences

Tags: regex, sed, backreference

I have text in many html files that is in this format:

```html
<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
<div id="footer"> 
  <p align="right"> Slogan<br />
    5555 Street East <br />
    City, State 99999 <br />
    Call Us (555)555-5555 <br />
</p>
    
<div align="center">
<a class="footer" href="http://www.example.com" title="Site">Site</a>
</div>


 <br>

</div>
<!--END FOOTER-->
```

I am using this:

```
sed -E -i 's/(<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->)(.|\n)*(<!--END FOOTER-->)/\1 <br>REPLACE<br> \3 /m'  file.html
```

but not working to capture & backreference them:

```
\1 <!-- BEGIN FOOTER --> 
\3 <!--END FOOTER-->
```

And insert this in between them:

```
REPLACE
```

So trying to end up with this:

```html
<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
<br>REPLACE<br>
<!--END FOOTER-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->/{:a;N;/<!--END FOOTER-->/!ba;s/\n.*\n/\n<br>REPLACE<br>\n/}' file
```

This gathers up lines between footers and replaces the lines between with the required string.

An alternative (similar to revo);

```
sed '/<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->/,/<!--END FOOTER-->/!b;/<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->/b;/<!--END FOOTER-->/!d;i\<br>REPLACE<br>' file
```

Another way:

```
sed '/<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->/,/<!--END FOOTER-->/!b;/<!--END FOOTER-->/p | sed '/<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->/p;/<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->/,/<!--END FOOTER-->/c\<br>REPLACE<br>'
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` reads from input file one line at a time and directs the result to standard output. It means no where in input line there is `\n` character to be matched except in some cases that a few special commands are being used. You could use address ranges along with insert `i` command to achieve desired output:

```
sed '/BEGIN FOOTER/,/END FOOTER/{ /END FOOTER/{i\<br>REPLACE<br>
b}; /BEGIN FOOTER/b; d;}' file
```

Watch the linebreak after first line. `i` inserts data before current line in pattern space. `b` jumps over remaining commands causing a new iteration to be dobe. `/BEGIN FOOTER/,/END FOOTER/` implies a range in which the other commands should execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can first save the lines with `BEGIN FOOTER` and `END FOOTER` in `beg` and `end` variables:

```
beg=$(grep -n "BEGIN FOOTER" inputfile | cut -d: -f1)
end=$(grep -n "END FOOTER" inputfile| cut -d: -f1)
```

Then use sed's `c\` command:

```
sed -i.bak "$((beg+1)),$((end-1))c\<br>REPLACE<br>" inputfile
```

Result:

```
<!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
<br>REPLACE<br>
<!--END FOOTER-->
```

Alternatively use the single command:

```
sed "/BEGIN FOO/,/END FOO/c\<!--BEGIN FOOTER-->\n<br>REPLACE<br>\n<!--END FOOTER-->" inputfile
```